# Unpublish content automatically

Tags: nodes

Hi I want to know if there's a way to unpublish content(nodes) automatically based on a field date previously created.

I want that task to be automatically based on the current date.

Example:

The user already has a content with that field called "Deadline" filled with 20/01/2015 so, for now that content should be passed to unpublished.

If I can do it through some hook let me know to insert in my costume module, thx so much

Edit: I can't use the **Rules module** because whenever I try to add some condition to one Rule one error just pop up, and I can't continue, and I'm not gonna do a CLEAN installation .....

Comment: I think you should try to repair rules. Have you already created some rules?

Comment: arrubiu is correct - regardless of the outcome of this question, having a broken enabled module could become disastrous if left unchecked. Perhaps start a new question for the error message you are receiving.  Fixing that would answer this question, since Rules is the simplest option

Comment: @DarkteK : is your [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module still broken?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens I don't have access to that environment anymore, sorry, that was the way I found to do it in that moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed by myself, as I always do in this forum:

```
$query_get = db_query("SELECT n.nid, p.your_field_value FROM node as n INNER JOIN your_field_table as p ON p.entity_id = n.nid WHERE n.status = 1");

foreach($query_get as $row){
  $date1 = date('Y-m-d');
  $date2 = explode($row->your_field__value);
  if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($date2[0])){
  }else{
    $query_update = db_query("UPDATE {node} SET status = 0 WHERE nid =".$row->nid);
  }
}
```

You can place this inside your custom module.

Answer (score 0):

you cane do it by [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules/)

please check this [article](https://groups.drupal.org/node/240678) it will help if you are new in rules module

Comment: Already tried that, but my Rule module is broken